# ViewPager Animate views inside fragment

Tags: android

I wants to animate views(like scale/zoom views) inside the Fragment attached in ViewPager.

```
mPager = findViewById(R.id.feedsPager);
mAdapter = new FeedAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mPager.setCurrentItem(pagePosition, false);
```

**Code for Animation:**

```
feedImage.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.feed_detail_image_animation));
```

**feed_detail_image_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="false" >
    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="100%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />
</set>
```

But the problem is the animation on the views inside the first opened fragment in ViewPager is not smooth(and sometimes views event not animate or animate with jerk). However if I set the animation on views with some delay inside the fragment, then its working fine.

Please help, if any body have any idea

Comment: Please show us the code you use for animating views, it will help with solving your problem.

Comment: @Rafal Zawadzki, I have added the code for animation, please check

Comment: This might be related to few things and with more code it will be difficult to debug. But I would look into: 1) when is the animation started? Maybe it's too early during the initialisation of the fragment? You have a minimal offscreen page limit so there is lots of initialisation going on with each swipe 2) Maybe its not about the animation but something is working on the main thread? 3) Is the hardware acceleration switched off? Animations might be jerky in this case
Some code of the fragment `onCreate` and `onViewCreate` etc might help